# Is there any console REPL for Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, console, read-eval-print-loop, swift-playground

Is there some console interface for Swift?

For example with Ruby, Python(or even Scala) I can run a REPL and check something. Like this(example from Python REPL):

```
>>> [1] + [2] 
[1, 2]
```

I know about playgrounds but they are slow(Interface is slow) and annoying if you want to check something

Comment: Right from the main Swift page https://developer.apple.com/swift/: "**Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL).**  The LLDB debugging console in Xcode includes an interactive version of the Swift language built right in. Use Swift syntax to evaluate and interact with your running app, or write new code to see how it works in a script-like environment. Available from within the Xcode console **or in Terminal.**"

Comment: @MartinR Ok, so how should I run it?

Comment: [Introduction to the Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18) from the Swift blog. Also answered in the referenced thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in the terminal:

```
xcrun swift
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: I can do it only after 10 minutes, 3 left:)